# eks cluster - adding worker nodes - how does applying a configmap makes my nodes visible to the k8s cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm trying out AWS EKS following this guide https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/aws/eks-intro

I understand all the steps except for the last one where the instructions say to `apply a configmap`. Before this step, I couldn't see my worker nodes from the cluster `kubectl get nodes`. But, I can see my worker nodes after applying this configmap. Can someone please explain to me how this configmap actually accomplishes this feat.

Here is the configmap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - rolearn: ${aws_iam_role.demo-node.arn}
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
      groups:
        - system:bootstrappers
        - system:nodes
```

Thanks,

Ashutosh Singh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in that configmap are what enables the worker node to join the cluster. Specifically, it needs the proper role ARN permissions. In the tutorial you are following, look at how `aws_iam_role.demo-node.arn` is defined, then look up the permissions associated with those policies. You can experiment around and remove/add other policies and see how it affects the node's ability to interact with the cluster.

Comment: I think my confusion is around how does a kubernetes configmap allows a worker node (aws EC2 instance) to join the kubernetes cluster via IAM role. Is it somehow related to how `aws-iam-authenticator` works?

Comment: Sure. The policies attached to the role are AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy, AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy, and AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly (look at the definitions for these on the aws console). Without these, the worker node would still *try* to join, but be denied. The worker node is *trying* to connect because that's how the AMI is configured. I believe you could remove the AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly policy, and the node would join, but it would be unable to pull from your ECR. Without AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy, it wouldn't be able to `ec2:DescribeInstances` so it wouldnt even find master.